# Is there a way of getting feedback from a Future function in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, future

I have this Future function that takes a lot of time to load, and it works basically like a video render (it executes some steps 100 times).
Is there a way I could display the progress in a widget? 
I tried setting a global variable in MyApp() for example an int corresponding to the frame and via `setState(`) I tried rebuilding the widget, but it didn't work, the application freezes and the widget doesn't get updated.

This is the function:

```
int _progress = 0;

Future _cycleGame() async {
    await game.cycle((int value) {
      print(value);


      setState(() {
        _progress = value;
      });

    }).whenComplete(() {

      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

The `game.cycle()` is a Future function that cyles 50 times.

game.cycle() function for reference:

```
Future cycle(Function cBack) async {

    for (int i in Range(50)) {
      if (!shouldFinish) {

        cBack(i);
        ///Does things.
```

And as of now I'm using simply a text in the screen to the `_progress` value.
The vlaue gets printed right (one every tot time) but the text displaying the `_progress` only updates at the end of the function. What Am I doing wrong?

I tried googling for how to do it but I found nothing. Is this possible?

**Edit 1**.
Using the answer provided by Rémi Rousselet, I still couldn't get the code to work. The widget gets updated only when the stream ends.

this is the code.

```
    import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home: Foo(),
    );
  }
}


class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  Stream<int> _cycleStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cycleStream = cycle();


  }

  Stream<int> cycle() async* {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
      sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 100));



      yield i;

      this.setState(() {

      });

      // does things
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(

      stream: _cycleStream,
      initialData: 0,


      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        return Center(
          child: Text(snapshot.data.toString())
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter Doctor

`[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.17134.706], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at 
    • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (8 days ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)`

Comment: You could make that long-running function take a callback that it can periodically invoke to provide progress information.  The caller then could provide a callback that invokes `setState` with the reported progress.

Comment: As you have a set of events that you want to observe(the intermediary steps) look into using a Stream instead of a Future.

Comment: @jamesdlin I tried passing a function to the long-running fu nction which of this type `(value) {_progress = value; setState(() {});}.` but the layout only gets updated as the function ends.

Comment: @Luksprog  any clue on how to do that?

Comment: @fabriziog Your long-running function probably does not yield (e.g. by using `await`).

Comment: @fabriziog Post the code you have.

Comment: I've added the code and also tried using await, but I still didn't get any result. Am I  doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a `Future`, you likely want a `Stream`.

`Future` only emits a value when they are completely finished. As such we can't use them to represent a value that changes over time (here a progress indicator).

A `Stream` on the other hand can emit an unlimited number of times.

Here's an implementation of your `cycle` function that emits the current progress every time it updates:

```
Stream<double> cycle() async* {
  for (int i in Range(50)) {
    yield i / 50;
    // TODO: does things
  }
}
```

You can then send that `double` into a `CircularProgressIndicator` using `StreamBuilder`.

Here's a full example:

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  Stream<double> _cycleStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cycleStream = cycle();
  }

  Stream<double> cycle() async* {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
      yield i / 50;
      // does things
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<double>(
      stream: _cycleStream,
      initialData: 0,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator(
          value: snapshot.data,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I still can't get it to work. I copied the text in your answer and tried adding a `sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 100));` before the yield in the cycle to simulate the function I should use but still the circle loads completely as soon as I run the app. Am I missing something? And for debugging, I added a print(i) in the cycle and the number get printed one every 100 milliseconds but the circle only updates on 50.0

Comment: It basically just updates on the first time (0.0) and last (1.0)

Comment: Have you tried only using `yield i` in the above example rather than `yield i/50`. It will yield the actual value of i rather than the division quotient.

Comment: We need more information on the "didn't work".  It's hard to guess without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: I added the code and the flutter doctor for the current app that doesn't work

Comment: @Rémi Rousselet I tried the other answer, but it didn't work. I think the right choice is StreamBuilder but I still can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Future Builder ?

```
Future < Widget > buildAfter() async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => Text('Hello World!'));
}

return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: buildAfter(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            title: snapshot.data,
            subtitle: Text('Counter: $index'),
          ),
        );
      }
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  ));
```

In this code when you will run it will display the CircularProgressIndiacator for 3 seconds because we have told the compiler to hold for 3 seconds in the Future function.

And when the 3 seconds are over it returns the data, FutureBuilder get's a notification that it has the data and to rebuild the widget with the new data available.

Note: It's not necessary to that your Future function has to return necessary data, all it needs to return something other than error so that listening Builder function can understand when it's should to rebuild itself.

Hopefully you can also Future Builder can be used within any widget.

*If you want to emit data multiple time you can use a FutureBuilder with a bool and check if it's loading then show this else show that. Instead of Stream/Streambuilder and making things less complicated.*

```
bool isLoading = false;

Future < Widget > buildAfter() async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => Text('Hello World!'));
}

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    backgroundColor: greenColor,
    title: const Text('Inbox'),
      actions: < Widget > [
        new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.edit),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = !isLoading;
            });
          }),
      ],
  ),
  body: isLoading ?
  Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
    ),
  ) :
  FutureBuilder(
    future: buildAfter(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text('Code'),
            subtitle: Text('Counter: $name'),
          ),
        );
      }
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  ));
```

What's happening in this code is it check the bool isLoading

if isLoading == true => Show Circular Progress Indicator

if isLoading == false => Show future builder

So when you have to call it multiple times you can setState of bool isLoading to true. Then after your calculation is over you can setState of bool isLoading to false.

But it depends on the use case Streams are always better when you have incoming events at anytime, but if you know what you're doing else Streams make themselves complicated to understand

Answer (score 0):

according to you said you couldn't get the code to work.

I've already try Remo's code and it's working fine.

I think the issue is your cycle() need await for simulating some delay.

```js
Stream<double> cycle() async* {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
      yield i / 50;

      // does things
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
  }
```